# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Decision Tree

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, reshape, decision-tree

[image]

[image]

Hi, is there any way to fix the Value Error and plot the right graph?

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn import tree
dt_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(dt_clf.score(X_test,y_test))

X_train.shape

y_train.shape

X_test.shape

y_test.shape


dt_clf.predict(np.array([6,3,5.5,1]).reshape(1,4))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=500)
tree.plot_tree(dt_clf,fontsize=3) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the errors say, you have created a model with 784 features. So you need to pass the same amount of feature when using `predict`

```
dt_clf.predict(np.array([6,3,5.5,1]).reshape(1,4))
```

The NumPy array here should be shaped `(1, 784)`

Or you can adapt `fit`, and use only 4 feature, so `X_train` will be `(60000, 4)`

Comment: Thank you! I tried (1, 784), however, it appears like this: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-302273918ddc> in <module>
----> 1 dt_clf.predict(np.array([6,3,5.5,1]).reshape(1, 784))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (1,784)

Comment: Your np.array has only 4 values, you need to pass 784 values in it.  Reshape can't create the 780 missing values to obtain a  (1, 784) shape

Comment: Thank you for the help! What should I do to pass 784 values in it?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass 784 values in it because you pass 784 values when you used `fit`. If you want to use 4 values, you have to limit the values you pass to `fit`